# RoR Guide With "No route matches [POST] "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the [official Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) chapter 5.11

got the _form.html.rb as

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2>
            <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %>
            prohibited this article from being saved:
        </h2>
        <ul>
            <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li>
                    <%= msg %>
                </li>
            <% end %>
        <ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>
```

and a new and an editing page like:

```
<h1>New Article</h1>
<%= render 'form', method: :get %>
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

but when I finished the editing, it logged :"No route matches [POST] "/articles/2/edit""
and the "rake routes" command shows

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)     welcome#index
     articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
              POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
  new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
 edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
      article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
              PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
         root GET    /                            welcome#index
```

I have checked the code of the rendered HTML file. The method of the form is POST.

Btw. I don't think changing the routes file is a correct way. Because I think the there must be something wrong with my code, as the guide didn't do anything else to the routes file.

Comment: No need to pass the `method: :get` externally to render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the `new.html.erb` to

```
<h1>New Article</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

and typo error `_form.html.rb` to `_form.html.erb`

Comment: Oh Thank you so so much. However, at first, "the method: :get" was not added, and I got the question. And I added that, the question still there. But , when I removed it this time, it worked. I was very confused. But it finally worked, I think maybe the cache or sth else's reason.     And thank you again.